# WebService in Lotus Domino in Java getting the IP Address of the Client

Tags: web-services, ip-address, lotus-domino

We have written a webservice provider in Java in Lotus Domino. Now we would like to obtain the IP Address of the webservice Consument, but unfortunately this is not easy.

My first try was :

```
 mc = MessageContext.getCurrentContext();
 String remoteAddr = "REMOTE_ADDR?" + mc.getProperty("REMOTE_ADDR");
```

Second try:

```
String remoteIP = mc.getStrProp(Constants.MC_REMOTE_ADDR);
```

Not working as well.

So i have tried to get all properties available in the MessageContext

```
Iterator x = mc.getPropertyNames();

      while (x.hasNext()) {

        String strX = x.next().toString();

// OutPut of the strX

      }
```

And the output was:

```
RPC
transport.url
```

Well, nothing helpfull.

Has anybody found a working solution?

According to this blog [http://www.unimatrix-0.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50:messagecontext-im-domino-webservice&catid=35:webservices&Itemid=55](http://www.unimatrix-0.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50%3amessagecontext-im-domino-webservice&catid=35%3awebservices&Itemid=55) in the old version there were only a few properties, which were distributed from axis.

Thanx a lot for any idea.

Comment: Might help to explain why you need this. It can certainly be gotten from the Admin side of things.

Comment: Thanx Simon. In Lotus Script it was easy to get this info. I need to check if the client has access to the webservice not only according to the credentials, but to the ip address as well.

Comment: just wondering if this could work: Session s = WebServiceBase.getCurrentSession();
  String resu="";
  try {
   resu = "hello, your IP is " + s.evaluate("Remote_Addr").toString();

well no... I tried

Comment: WS Providers are basically web agents. So does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20735624/1167890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebServiceBase.getAgentSession().getAgentContext().getDocumentContext().getItemValueString("Remote_Addr");

note: there might be easier way to get AgentContext, but this works. and as long as it compiles..:-)